# phonegap jquery mobile window.innerHeight() doesn't match screen resolution?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, resolution

Okay so I have a phonegap + jquery mobile app with an splash screen image at 720×1280 because that is the screen size of the test device. So when I run the app the splash screen displays properly at the right resolution. But when I try to use the same image as the background-img for my app page the only thing viewable is an enlarged corner of the image. And the window.width is set 360px not the 720px of the resolution. Does anyone know what could be going wrong? And why does the window.width and window.height not match the screen resolution?

I have searched around and I am using this line in my html file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

But experimenting with this meta did seem to have any effect...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Fixed it! Just had to change the above meta tag to this line :  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

Comment: However I am still having a problem with this on iOS as the above only fixed it for android...